# Summoning moderators on chat doesn't work with markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-abilities

If a moderator summons site mods on chat, chat doesn't convert markdown in the message into HTML:

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

Comment: You cast a spell at the moderator. Unfortunately, your spell summons a dragon and you die.

Comment: You cast a spell at the devs.  Unfortunately, your spell summons a Wedontgiveaflipasaurus and you die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a chat feature that *only* works in the moderator room and given the way it's implemented, I really don't want to spend any time on making something work that isn't even remotely vital for this feature.

Do you want to contact a moderator of another site, or do you **want** to ***have*** <s>*awesome*</s> *formatting* in **<s>your</s> *message?***

Update: After a recent change to how reply bots are implemented, this works as expected now.

Comment: Any chance of an exception for links? I often contact other sites' mods to ask them about a specific question. Not a big deal if it's too complex to implement, but it'd be a "nice to have".

Comment: as @AnnaLear said, links are pretty important, can we at least have link formatting?

Comment: @AnnaLear Links work. `[markdown](links://)` don't, but just posting a URL will linkify it.

Comment: I second @AnnaLear statement and I've asked for that specifically in chat; most of the times I've used it and seen it used to summon mods, it was to show them a link for migration (and I don't just include the link, I link the title), and enabling the link helps make it much easier for all of us.

Comment: @balpha I meant the formatting. Like I said, not a big deal, but if you ever have some free time... :) Come to think of it... would it be hard to make it recognize that a link points to a question and linkify it with a title (kinda like what happens when a link is pasted into a post on the site)? That'd probably make for the most immediately readable/useful mod messages.

Comment: @AnnaLear It would probably be easier if they made all chat-enabled markdown work there rather than add an exception to links.

Comment: If its *important* you can ping them twice.  **Really important** three times, and if it is ***super duper important*** keep on pinging them until someone shows up.